# Node sever not rune

Tags: node.js, nodemon, nodejs-server

node server can't start and show many type errors like disabled problem and function not allow any many off please give me some of effective command to run node server and open this website in local server.

How i run node server?

Comment: Without knowing the errors that you are getting it's a bit difficult to understand what the problem is. You have to provide your code, the commands that you are trying to execute and the errors that you get.